# Is it possible 3D brush react native / drawing using AR

Tags: react-native, 3d, expo, augmented-reality, visualbrush

I'm planning a new project and we decided to use **react native** and **expo**.
But we have that one requirement that is:
The user can draw 3D in real life using camera.

*Would it be possible for us to pull this off?
Or we should change react native?*

If you have questions please do ask.

- If you familiar with TikTok, it is that filter where you drow around the room and it stays were you draw it (AR BRUSH).